# How to convert boolean array to binary and vice versa in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, binary, encode

What is the most efficient way to output a boolean array to (and input from) a file in Java? I was going to use a string with each character being either 't' or 'f' and then I thought, why not take eight time less space?

**NOTE**

I actually have no idea which answer is the better method, I've just chosen Peter's because I understand it. Thanks to both answerers!

Comment: The general outcome will be to convert the boolean array to a byte array (where 1 bit is one boolean) and output that to file. The question then becomes how to do such a thing efficiently. Do you only have to store the bits in the file, or are you requiring a specific file format?

Comment: Hi @owlstead, thanks for your reply. no, no specific file format. the file will first indicate the size of the boolean array then the reading algorithm will use this to know how many more succeeding bytes of the file represent the array.

Comment: Interesting, that does sound like a file format. What's the maximum size (if any) of the number of booleans?

Comment: @owlstead I thought you meant an already established file format. The max size for the array is 10K (ten thousand booleans)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have a boolean[]

```
boolean[] ar = {true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,false,true,false,false,false,true,tr‌​ue};
```

and you want to write this to a disk, and you don't care how its is implemented in memory.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    boolean[] ar = {true, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true};

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.dat");
    writeBooleans(out, ar);
    out.close();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.dat");
    boolean[] ar2 = new boolean[ar.length]; 
    readBooleans(in, ar2);
    in.close();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar2));
    System.out.println("The file size was "+new File("test.dat").length()+" bytes.");
}

private static void writeBooleans(OutputStream out, boolean[] ar) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i += 8) {
        int b = 0;
        for (int j = Math.min(i + 7, ar.length-1); j >= i; j--) {
            b = (b << 1) | (ar[j] ? 1 : 0);
        }
        out.write(b);
    }
}

private static void readBooleans(InputStream in, boolean[] ar) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i += 8) {
        int b = in.read();
        if (b < 0) throw new EOFException();
        for (int j = i; j < i + 8 && j < ar.length; j++) {
            ar[j] = (b & 1) != 0;
            b >>>= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
[true, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true]
[true, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true]
The file size was 2 bytes.
```

but if I look at how big the file actually is

```
$ ls -l test.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter 2 2012-02-19 14:04 test.dat
$ du -h test.dat 
4.0K    test.dat
```

It says the length is 2 bytes, but the disk space used is actually 4 KB.

Note: About 1 minute of your time is worth about the same as 80 MB of SSD (expensive disk, more for HDD) So if you don't think you will be saving at least 80 MB by using this, you could be wasting your time. ;)

---

You can use BitSet, which can take 16x less space as each character is 16-bit.

Comment: BitSet is not a file, please read the question before answering.

Comment: @Peter Great! could you show me how? What is the best way to store and retrieve `boolean[] ar = {true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,false,true,false,false,false,true,true};` to and from a file?

Comment: Each character is 16bit? Not on disk, it's not: depends entirely on the encoding -- and, say, UTF-8 needs only 8bits for `t` or `f`. Still I agree the concept of bitmasks is the way to go for space efficiency: length = O(n) + 1, with n the length of the boolean array.

Comment: @owlstead It doesn't say it has to *be* a file it says *from* a file which implies it is something else.  Please read the question before trying to correct someone. ;)

Comment: Yeah, right :) Personally I hate BitSet as it does not provide any conversion methods. Same with EnumSet really. I've written some library functions for both which I should really send to Joshua Bloch.

Comment: @owlstead true, but if you Serialize it, it can be written to disk.  The amount of disk space you need to save to make it worth worrying about how it is written means the overhead of Serialization doesn't matter too much. e.g. the above example, the file size would be much larger but still use the same disk space.

Comment: @owlstead I agree some int or long-wise operations would be useful.

Comment: Serialization of BitSet would certainly be a possibility, as internally it simply stores long values, so the amount of overhead would be (more or less) a constant, not a multiple of the bit size. It says so in the serialization part of the API. Of course, it would make it language & API (version) dependent, which is possibly not what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Newly created, just for you. I'll leave the `BooleanInputStream` as an excercise. Note that the first bit is now the rightmost (MSB) bit in the file (remove `Byte.SIZE - 1 -` in the example for other byte order, whatever you prefer). Simply use e.g. DataOutputStream to write the size of the thing to file first. 10K should fit in an integer.

Note that storing a boolean array of 10K elements is very inefficient memory wise, you certainly should use `BitSet` for that (finally, somebody who needs `BitSet`)!

```
public final class BooleanOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    private int bitIndex;
    private byte buffer;

    public BooleanOutputStream(final OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public void writeBoolean(final boolean value) throws IOException {
        buffer ^= (value ? 1 : 0) << (Byte.SIZE - 1 - bitIndex++);
        if (bitIndex == Byte.SIZE) {
            write(buffer & 0xFF);
            buffer = 0;
            bitIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is an encoder and does therefore not close the underlying stream.
     * Please close underlying stream separately.
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (bitIndex != 0) {
            out.write(buffer);
            buffer = 0;
            bitIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

public class BooleanInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    private int bitIndex;
    private byte buffer;

    public BooleanInputStream(final InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public boolean readBoolean() throws IOException {
        if (bitIndex == 0) {
            int b = read();
            if (b == -1) {
                throw new EOFException();
            }
            buffer = (byte) b;
        }

        boolean value = (buffer & (1 << (Byte.SIZE - 1 - bitIndex++))) != 0;
        if (bitIndex == Byte.SIZE) {
            bitIndex = 0;
        }
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * This is a decoder and therefore does not close the underlying stream.
     * Please close underlying stream separately.
     */    
    public void close() throws IOException {
        buffer = 0;
        bitIndex = 0;
    }
}
```