# Method for converting boolean array to binary java

Tags: java, arrays, binary, boolean

Is there already a specific method for converting a Boolean array to a binary array or would I just need a for loop?

Comment: You can check java docs before asking.

Comment: What do you mean "binary array"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serialize boolean array, check this: [How to convert boolean array to binary and vice versa in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349519/how-to-convert-boolean-array-to-binary-and-vice-versa-in-java)

If you want to use bits instead of booleans, check `BitSet` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

> This class implements a vector of bits that grows as needed. Each
>   component of the bit set has a boolean value. The bits of a BitSet are
>   indexed by nonnegative integers. Individual indexed bits can be
>   examined, set, or cleared. One BitSet may be used to modify the
>   contents of another BitSet through logical AND, logical inclusive OR,
>   and logical exclusive OR operations.
>
> By default, all bits in the set initially have the value false.

You can use these methods:

[BitSet#set(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int%29) to set the bit to `true` at specified position.
[BitSet#clear(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#clear%28int%29) to set the bit to `false` at specified position.